# Does 12.04 have 24 bit 96000 sound?

Tags: soundcard

If not I will stick with the early version as it is more stable and I am very happy with it.

Comment: why would it not have 24 bit 96000 sound? I would consider it a degression if it did not :)

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware will determine what quality of sound you have.  Linux has supported 24-bit 9600 sound for quite a while now and there is no reason support would be dropped.

Comment: I really tried to get it to work, did a lot of google searching. Downloaded almost every audio software avilable, even tried messing with some files, I forgot where. And I could not get anything higher than cd quality.